# One drive API to fetch presentation permission from One drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

We have an internal application to share PowerPoint presentations among our marketing Team using one drive business account. This app basically handles the versions and we need to keep the same version for all the edited ones including their permissions. ie, one drive should not treat the same presentation as new presentation.
 Is there any One drive API available to fetch the presentation permission’s?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API has a OneDrive API which you can use to manage file permissions.

The following URL's should help:

[Access OneDrive and SharePoint in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online)

[File Permissions - One Drive API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/permission?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: Is there any One drive API available to fetch the shared presentation permission’s?

Comment: The DriveItem that you return from the API has a relationship to permissions. A JSON representation of DriveItem exists here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: I've tried the following ways but all threw a 404 error.

Comment: var permissions = await graphClient.Sites["My site ID"].Drive.Items["ItemID"].Permissions
                            .Request(requestOptions)
                            .WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount())
                            .GetAsync()

Comment: var permissixons = await graphClient.Groups["group ID"].Drive.Items["Item ID"].Permissions
                            .Request(requestOptions)
                            .WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount())
                            .GetAsync();

Comment: var permissionss = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["Item ID"].Permissions
                            .Request(requestOptions)
                            .WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount())
                            .GetAsync();

Comment: I can't tell why you're getting the 404 errors. It could be the parameters you're using. The Graph Explorer might be helpful: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer